# Javascript HTML DOM wont put content in seperate cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

this is my first attempt at using javascript HTML DOM. Im trying to put the content of the birds (the name and an image) in seperate cards but it instead it puts them all in the same card. I'm guessing my problem lies in the divs part of my javascript but I dont understand how to fix this. Can someone help me?

```js
const cardsContainer = document.querySelector("#cards")
const birdNames = ["Koolmees", "Specht", "kerkuil"]
const birdImages = ["https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2", "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg", "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg"]
const birds = [
    { name: "Koolmees", image: "https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2" },
    { name: "specht", image: "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg" },
    { name: "kerkuil", image: "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg" }
]

function addCard(birdImage, birdName){
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("div")
    cardDiv.classList.add("card")
    cardsContainer.appendChild(cardDiv)

    const img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = birdImage
    cardDiv.appendChild(img)

    const nameDiv = document.createElement("div")
    nameDiv.innerText = birdName
    cardDiv.appendChild(nameDiv)


}

function addCards(){
    for(let i = 0; i<birdNames.length; i++){
        addCard(birdImages[i], birdNames[i])
    }
}

addCards()
```

```css
flex-container {
    /* We first create a flex layout context */
    display: flex;

    /* Then we define the flow direction
       and if we allow the items to wrap
     * Remember this is the same as:
     * flex-direction: row;
     * flex-wrap: wrap;
     */
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
    justify-content: space-around;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

flex-item {
    background: #ABEBC6;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #1565C0;
}


wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

wrapper > * {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

header {
    background: #DAF7A6;
}

footer {
    background: #28B463;
}

main {
    text-align: left;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

aside {
    background: #28B463;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    main    { flex: 3 0px; }
    aside   { order: 1; }
    main    { order: 2; }
    footer  { order: 3; }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    nav li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}

p1 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

p2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p3 {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Test week 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<wrapper>
    <header><p1>Vogel magazine voor vogelspotters!</p1></header>
    <main>
        <flex-container>
            <flex-item id="cards"></flex-item>
        </flex-container>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside 1</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</wrapper>

<script src="js/DOM2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `function addCard(birdImage, birdName)` change `const cardDiv = document.createElement("div")` by `const cardDiv = document.createElement("flex-item")`, remove the flex-item tag   and pass the `id="cards` to `<flex-container id="cards">`

```js
const cardsContainer = document.querySelector("#cards")
const birdNames = ["Koolmees", "Specht", "kerkuil"]
const birdImages = ["https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2", "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg", "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg"]
const birds = [
    { name: "Koolmees", image: "https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2" },
    { name: "specht", image: "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg" },
    { name: "kerkuil", image: "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg" }
]

function addCard(birdImage, birdName){
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("flex-item")
    cardDiv.classList.add("card")
    cardsContainer.appendChild(cardDiv)

    const img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = birdImage
    cardDiv.appendChild(img)

    const nameDiv = document.createElement("div")
    nameDiv.innerText = birdName
    cardDiv.appendChild(nameDiv)


}

function addCards(){
    for(let i = 0; i<birdNames.length; i++){
        addCard(birdImages[i], birdNames[i])
    }
}

addCards()
```

```css
flex-container {
    /* We first create a flex layout context */
    display: flex;

    /* Then we define the flow direction
       and if we allow the items to wrap
     * Remember this is the same as:
     * flex-direction: row;
     * flex-wrap: wrap;
     */
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
    justify-content: space-around;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

flex-item {
    background: #ABEBC6;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #1565C0;
}


wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

wrapper > * {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

header {
    background: #DAF7A6;
}

footer {
    background: #28B463;
}

main {
    text-align: left;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

aside {
    background: #28B463;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    main    { flex: 3 0px; }
    aside   { order: 1; }
    main    { order: 2; }
    footer  { order: 3; }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    nav li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}

p1 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

p2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p3 {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Test week 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<wrapper>
    <header><p1>Vogel magazine voor vogelspotters!</p1></header>
    <main>
        <flex-container id="cards">
           
        </flex-container>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside 1</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</wrapper>

<script src="js/DOM2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```